# Xamarin Android Google Sign In OnConnected Callback never thrown

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-plus

Iam trying to implement Google+ Sign-In into my Xamarin Android Application. I just got an Activity which shows a Google+-Button for SignIn. But the OnConnected Callback is never thrown by the ApiClient.

I implement the interfaces:

```
GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener
```

In OnCreate i initialize the Google-Stuff:

```
var googleLogin = FindViewById<SignInButton>(Resource.Id.google_login);
googleLogin.SetSize(SignInButton.SizeWide);
googleLogin.Click += GoogleLogin_Click;

_googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
.AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.AddApi(PlusClass.API)
.AddScope(new Scope(Scopes.Profile))
.Build();
```

If someone click the Google-SignIn i call following:

```
private void GoogleLogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   _googleApiClient.Connect();
}
```

And then i thought i could get user information this way:

```
public void OnConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
{
  var people = PlusClass.PeopleApi.GetCurrentPerson(_googleApiClient);
}
```

Hint: GetCurrentPerson is marked as deprecated if someone knows how to solve this the modern way please tell me :)

In OnStop() i just disconnect the client. But my problem is that OnConnected is never called. Do i miss something? I registered the App in developer console for sure. There are several threads for this but nothing help me so far :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying changing your scope to `DriveClass.ScopeFile`:

```
_googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Application.Context)
    .UseDefaultAccount()
    .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .AddApi(PlusClass.API)
    .AddScope(PlusClass.ScopePlusLogin)
    .Build();
```

That should get `Connect` to call your `OnConnectionFailed` callback where you can handle the `ConnectionResult` and after the user selects an account|signs-in your `OnConnected` will eventaully be called...

Update:

#### Manually Managed Connection Example:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener
{
    GoogleApiClient client;
    bool _resolvingError;
    const string TAG = "MyGPlus";
    const int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 999;

    public void OnConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "OnConnected");
    }

    public void OnConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "OnConnectionFailed");
        if (_resolvingError)
            return;
        if (result.HasResolution)
        {
            try
            {
                _resolvingError = true;
                result.StartResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
            }
            catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
            {
                Log.Debug(TAG, e.Message);
                client.Connect();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ShowErrorDialog(result.ErrorCode);
        }
    }

    void ShowErrorDialog(int errorCode)
    {
        var dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
        var args = new Bundle();
        args.PutInt("dialog_error", errorCode);
        dialogFragment.Arguments = args; 
        dialogFragment.Show(FragmentManager, "errordialog");
    }

    public void OnConnectionSuspended(int cause)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "OnConnectionSuspended");
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                if (!client.IsConnecting && !client.IsConnected)
                {
                    client.Connect();
                }
            }
            else if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
            {
                Log.Debug(TAG, "Result.Canceled");
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Application.Context)
                                        .UseDefaultAccount() .EnableAutoManage()

                .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .AddApi(PlusClass.API)
                .AddScope(PlusClass.ScopePlusLogin)
                .Build();
            _resolvingError = false;
            client.Connect();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: OnConnectionFailed gets called now :). But how can I trigger a sign in? Thought google will do this for me...

Comment: @Sebi No, you have to handle it unless you are using an Auto Managed connection via the builder's `EnableAutoManage` and have implemented a `FragmentActivity`... I'll add a manually managed connection example to the answer...

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the user is able to select an account. My OnActivityResult Method always gets Result.Canceled even if I log in with my account... So the OnConnected Event is further not reached.

Comment: @Sebi If you are getting `Result.Canceled`, the odds are your app is not registered in the Google API Console with the GPlus API  and/or your app is not signed with the keystore you told the Console you were using (via the SHA1 key).

Comment: Ok thank you very much i will check my configuration again.

Comment: @Sebi Assuming you are using Xamarin's default **debug** keystone, make sure that that SHA1 is used in the Console (see link)... you can update it later to a custom release keystore for submitting to the Play Store... https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/MD5_SHA1/

Comment: I got the wrong key now it is working fine :) Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sebi Can you ask another question for that one, thanks